# Sharing configuration among multiple Tomcat servers - best practices

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In our environment we have six identical Apache-Tomcat servers. The servers are hosted on Amazon EC2.
The configuration is taken from the local spring file.
The problem with that is that if a change is required to the configuration, we need to modify the spring file on each of the six servers.

I am feeling that we are doing some wrong - is there a better way? Maybe there is a way to share a spring file between the servers? What are the best practices?

Comment: Look at automation tools like chef and puppet. There are quite a few different options, but the learning curve may be a bit high for very occasional changes.